# Why are my particles starting off like this?

Tags: particles

So I have an emitter that's spinning (its a cylinder inside the black sphere). I have my first particle system set to loop by starting it at -210-210 and the second one starting at 210-630 (420 frames, 30fps)

Any idea whats going on? :/

This is the issue...

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like (taken after 100 frames)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
Had to start the cylinder rotation on a negative frame along with the start of the particle system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)